# Azure Event Grid : Events are not getting generated when an external application like spark writes into Blob

Tags: azure, pyspark, azure-eventgrid

**step1 :**
Written data to data lake gen2 with pyspark

parquet format :

```
Item.write.format("parquet").mode("overwrite").save("abfss://containerName@datalakeName.dfs.core.windows.net/parquet/Item/")
```

csv format:

```
Item.write.format("csv").mode("overwrite").save("abfss://containerName@datalakeName.dfs.core.windows.net/csv/Item/")
```

**Step2:**

I see that blobs were created successfully
[image]

But event are not being sent to the event hub topic when these blobs are created.

The event is getting triggered when we manually uploaded a file or renamed existing file in the storage.

[image]

Event which got triggered for this

[image]

**Summary**: Events are not getting generated when an external application like spark writes into Blob. They are only triggering when file is uploaded/renamed/ deleted manually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question,

This problem happened because the storage account was a Data Lake Gen1. I've mistakenly created Gen 1 instead of Gen2.

Upgrading the account to Gen2 resolved the issue.